Harmonic conjugate in a perspective of center $C \notin r$

Let $f: P_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ be an involutive perspective with axis $r$ and center $C \notin r$,i.e, the fixed points of $f$ are those that belong to $r$ and also $C$. Given $P \notin \{C\} \cup r$, let $P'$ be the image of $P$ by $f$ and $Q=CP \cap r$.


Show that $P'$ is the harmonic conjugate of $P$ with respect to the pair $(C,Q)$.

As $f$ is an homography, $$[C,Q,P,P']=[C,Q,P',P] \quad(f^2=id)$$
So  $[C,Q,P,P']^2=1$; but now how can I conclude that $[C,Q,P,P']=-1$?
EDIT:
As $P' \neq P$, $[C,Q,P,P'] \neq 1$
